# Pandas category is set to anything? after using of apply, but for-loop works

Tags: pandas, dataframe, apply

I have a complex df, where I use categories. As example here a small example with leads to the same problem. You see, df and df_cpy look initially like this:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"A": ['Apply','Strawberry','Cherry'],"B":['yes','yes','no'],"C":['green','red','red']})
df.B=df.B.astype("category")
df_cpy=df.copy()
```

|  | A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | Apply | yes | green |
| 1 | Strawberry | yes | red |
| 2 | Cherry | no | red |

Now i want to change all entries in C from green to yellow:

```
for i, row in df.iterrows():
    if row["C"]=='green':
        df.at[i, 'C'] = 'yellow'
```

This works fine, dtype of B "category" - which I didn´t touch - remains as it is:

```
df.dtypes
Out[92]: 
A      object
B    category
C      object
dtype: object
```

and the result is:

|  | A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | Apply | yes | yellow |
| 1 | Strawberry | yes | red |
| 2 | Cherry | no | red |

If I do the same operation with 'apply' instead, the values are also ok, but the category will be destroyed. It will be set back to 'object' - in my special case it is set to float64 - but I think this doesn´t matter. False is false. Why does this operation doesn´t work with apply?

```
def changer(row):
    if row["C"]=='green':
        row["C"]= 'yellow'
    return row

df_cpy=df_cpy.apply(changer,axis='columns')
```

Not ok, dtype of B will be set to 'object' in this example.

```
df_cpy.dtypes
Out[93]: 
A    object
B    object
C    object
dtype: object
```

The question is NOT how to exchange 'green' to 'yellow' in the best way. The question is why iteration over for-loop works and apply not.

As discussed in the comment:
Neither apply in combination with a function (doesn´t work here - first example) nor iterrows (works fine - second example) shall be used for clean programming.

I tried a third way
`df["C"] = df.apply(lambda x: 'yellow' if x["C"] == 'green' else x["C"], axis=1)`

Here also B believes type category.

But I´m searching for the cleanest way to do these changes without changing dtype category (in real there are more columns to edit, because of this I prefered the for-solution - also I have some conditions with not equal) - but what is best now? apply? for-loop with iterrow ... ?

Comment: You should use a loop: `df_cpy.loc[df_cpy['C'].eq('green'), 'C'] = 'red'`

Comment: Hi, yes - you´re right. But this is not the question. The example shall only show the different behaviour between two methods. I want to know, why the second method with "apply" doesn´t work - the exchange of 'green' to 'yellow' is not the question.

Comment: Because when applying a function per row (which you should almost never do), you create a new Series per row and lose the original dtype (unless you had a single dtype for the whole dataframe)

Comment: Ok, I understand. But is a for-loop an appropriate and professional way instead, as  described in my initial question? Please consider, that the change of values is in my real program much more complex and not possible to solve with your simple solution.

Comment: A for loop might be appropriate in some cases. When you cannot vectorize the operation. It's difficult to answer without a clear description of the desired operation. In any case, you almost never use `apply` on `axis=1` nor `iterrows`, those are particularly inefficient as they create Series intermediates for each row.

Comment: please [edit] the question with those details, it's difficult to read code in comments